# How deserialize the same JSON object but with diferent values into a java class

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

i have the following scenario:

some times i get this **JSON Object**

```
{"id": 1, "cp": "male", "money": 10.0, "startDate": "07:00", "endDate": "10:00"}
```

and others this one

```
{"id":1, "cp": "male", "money": 10.0, "startDate": 21600, "endDate": 32400}
```

as you can se the JSON has the same fields but some times the **startDate** and **endDate** are in diferent formats
in seconds in the second case.

y have simple java Class

```
public class Person {

    private Integer id;

    private String cp;

    private Double money;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToLocalTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalTime startDate;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToLocalTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalTime startDate;

    //Getter-Setter
```

### Converter

```
public class StringToLocalTimeConverter extends StdConverter<String, LocalTime> {

    static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME;

    @Override
    public LocalTime convert(String value) {


        Long number = Long.parseLong(value);

        return LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds(number);

    }

}
```

Obviously I'm getting a parse exception because I can't map both data values into the same LocalTime due to format.

Is it possible to map both **JSON objects** to the same Class? how can I workaround this or do I have to create separate Classes
what solution can be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , you can simply try parsing it with `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` first. If it fails , then you parse it as a long :

```
public class StringToLocalTimeConverter extends StdConverter<String, LocalTime> {

    static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME;

    @Override
    public LocalTime convert(String value) {
        try {
            return LocalTime.parse(value, DATE_FORMATTER);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {}

        Long number = Long.parseLong(value);
        return LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds(number);
    }

}
```

Comment: i will give this a try

Comment: Worked fine,i had a similar aproach but was missing the  try {}catch()